# Beamer table of contents with first section shaded

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm making a `beamer` presentation and I would like the table of contents to start with all the sections shaded, rather than with the first section already highlighted and subsequent sections shaded, which is the default behaviour for `pausesections`. I've tried looking for similar questions but to no avail.

The following almost works, but whilst the initial overlay has all the sections shaded (good), the second overlay jumps to highlighting both Section 1 **and** Section 2 (bad). I presume this is because the first overlay adds 1 to the `pausesections`-counter.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
\only<1>{\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=shaded]}
\only<2->{\tableofcontents[pausesections]}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

    \begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

    \begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    \end{frame}

\section{Section 3}

    \begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about splitting the table of contents into two slides?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Table of contents}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=shaded]
    \end{frame}

    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

    \begin{frame}{Table of contents}
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 1}

    \begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 2}

    \begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 3}

    \begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To prevent the change of the frame number after the first slide, just change the counter.

Comment: That's a neat solution, but unfortunately it adds 1 to the frame count. (I didn't include `\insertframenumber{}` in my MWE, but I'm using it the presentation that I'm writing.)

Comment: @DanielWolf Then you can just add a `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` between the first to slides. I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: D'oh! Of course. Great solution.

Comment: What about a table of contents in tow columns \tableofcontents[sections=6-]  and \tableofcontents[sections=-7]